# How to relate a group by count from one relation into another relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

I have following two schemas:

```
advisor(s_ID, i_ID)
instructor(ID, name, dept_name, credits)
```

I have calculated total number of i_ID occurrences for each distinct i_ID the following way:

```
SELECT i_ID, count(*)
FROM advisor
GROUP BY i_ID;
```

Each i_ID belongs to a dept_name. How do I get total count for each department name occurrences?

Example:

```
i_ID     count 
21         3
23         4
27         1
29         5
```

Suppose i_ID 21,23 belong to instructor(ID, physics) and i_ID 27,29 belong to instructor(ID, chemistry) then the output would be:

```
dept_name   count
physics       7(3+4)
chemistry     6(1+5)
```

Comment: i_ID is the foreign key . am i right ?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: although it named as ID in instructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
select dept name, 0 as total advised
from (select dept name from department
minus
select dept name
from instructor)
union
select dept name, count(*) as total advised
from instructor, advisor
where instructor.id = advisor.I ID
group by dept name
order by dept name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select a.dept_name,count(*) as count from instructor a join advisor b
    on a.ID=b.i_ID group by  a.ID
```